# Stripe error: The Token field is required

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

I can't get Store working with Stripe 1.6.5. I keep getting the Token is Required
messages. Can anyone see why this is happening?

Here is code in head tag:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('https://js.stripe.com/v1/', function() {
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_live_XXXXXXXX');
    });

  /* Ensure your checkout submit button has id="checkout_submit" */
  $("#checkout_submit").click(function() {

    /* Only handle requests for Stripe gateway */
    if (this.form.elements["payment_method"].value == "stripe") {

      /* Temporarily disable the checkout submit button */
      $("#checkout_submit").attr('disabled', true);

      /* Create a Stripe card token */
      Stripe.createToken({
        name: $("#payment_name").val(),
        number: $("#payment_card_no").val(),
        cvc: $("#payment_card_csc").val(),
        exp_month: $("#payment_exp_month").val(),
        exp_year: $("#payment_exp_year").val()
      }, stripeResponseHandler);

      /* We don't want to submit the form yet */
      return false;
    }
  });

  /* This function is triggered once Stripe has generated the token */
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    /* Re-enable the checkout submit button */
    $("#checkout_submit").attr('disabled', false);

    /* Check whether we have a valid credit card */
    if (response.error) {
      alert(response.error.message);
    } else {
      /* Set the card token and submit the checkout form */
      $("#payment_token").val(response['id']);
      $("#checkout_submit").unbind("click").click();
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the actual HTML

```
{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    return="store/order/ORDER_HASH"
    error_handling="inline"
    payment_method="stripe"
    error_delimiters='|'}
```

```
{if no_items}
    {redirect="store/checkout"}
{/if}

<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">

        <div class="row-store">
            <div class="span4">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Billing Details</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div><b>{billing_name}</b></div>
                        <div>{billing_address1}</div>
                        <div>{billing_address2}</div>
                        <div>{billing_address3} {billing_postcode}</div>
                        <div>{billing_region_name}</div>
                        <div>{billing_country_name}</div>
                        <div>{billing_phone}</div>
                        <div>{order_email}</div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Shipping Details</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        {if shipping_same_as_billing}
                            Same as Billing Details
                        {if:else}
                            <div><b>{shipping_name}</b></div>
                            <div>{shipping_address1}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_address2}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_address3} {shipping_postcode}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_region_name}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_country_name}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_phone}</div>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Payment</legend>

            {if error:payment_method}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="alert alert-error">{error:payment_method}</div>
                </div>
            {/if}

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="payment_method">Payment Method</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="payment_method" name="payment_method">
                        {payment_method_options}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="payment_card_no">Card No</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="payment_card_no" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="payment_name">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="payment_name" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="payment_exp_month">Expiry</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="payment_exp_month" style="width:auto">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        {exp_month_options}
                    </select>
                    <select id="payment_exp_year" style="width:auto">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        {exp_year_options}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="payment_csc">CSC</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="payment_card_csc" value="" class="input-mini" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="span4"><div class="well">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Order Summary</legend>

            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:60%">Product</th>
                        <th style="text-align:right">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item_qty} &times; {title}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{item_subtotal}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/items}
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                        <th style="text-align:right">{order_subtotal}</th>
                    </tr>
                    {if shipping_method_id}
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shipping ({shipping_method})</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{order_shipping}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/if}
                    {if order_tax_val}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{tax_name} ({tax_percent}%)</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{order_tax}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/if}
                    <tr>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th style="text-align:right">{order_total}</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div></div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <a href="{path='store/checkout2'}" class="btn">Back</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="payment_token" name="payment[token]" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="checkout_submit" value="Place Order" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
```

```
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Comment: Hi there - Stack Exchange is a community platform, it's not specific to Expresso (so no one can log in to your website, though we will follow up your email separately)

Comment: Have you checked whether the token field is actually getting submitted in the POST request to Store? You can see this in the Chrome or Firebug network tab.

Comment: It does not appear to be posting the token.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our email discussion, the actual problem was that jQuery was not loaded, and there were JS errors in the error console because `$` was not defined.

So for anyone else having this problem, it's worth checking your error console and make sure that the javascript is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your publishable key here?  This is specific to your stripe account.

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_live_XXXXXXXX');
```

Comment: I am using our LIVE key.  I just hid it in the post.  All is working other than the token is not being created.  I can't figure out why.

Comment: just keeps saying "The Token field is required."